# Flutter - How do I fix the app meta data so I can release my app to Google Play?

Tags: flutter, google-play-console

My Flutter based Android client keeps getting rejected from the Play Store for the following reason:

[image]

How do I fix these metadata values?

Answer (score 1):

As they have written it their feedback provide a proper description which will explain what the app is for, you can describe what the app does and probably mention the key features in your app.

Check the images uploaded, it should usually contain screenshots of your app.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what your app does and the name, description, etc, that you are submiting to google, i dont think we can help you.

But the probles is that google does not think that the description and images you are submiting reflect what your app does, and thus, making them misleading.

other option is the language you are using, maybe some words are not appropriate for their store.

Answer (score 1):

The short description of my Main store listing was exactly the same as the title of my app, which was causing the error.

I was able to fix the metadata issue by going to the app in google play console, then Main store listing, then updating the values there.